# Postgres/Rails => is object guaranteed to be persisted if I do .save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

If I have a model and save it like this:

```
model = Website.new
model.attr = 1
model.id = 1
model.save #assume no errors in saving
```

then retrieve it like this:

```
model2 = Website.find(1)
```

Will model2 always be returned? Ignoring errors saving to the database.

Is there a possible scenario where the data is not yet committed to the database, and as a result the find results in no records found? Do I need to delay the find to guarantee the row is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no database errors, and assuming you haven't overwritten `save` on `Website`, the only race condition you'd have is if you try to access the object (via `find` or otherwise) in the milliseconds before the record is created in the database.

So, to directly answer your question - yes, it's *possible* - but given a single database (e.g. no read-only slaves or anything like that), it's highly, highly unlikely.